# InvalidOperationException for ColorAnimation for WPF Grid.Background inside ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, background-color, controltemplate, invalidoperationexception, coloranimation

I'm customizing the stock WPF GroupBox control. I need to implement a color animation for its background when the mouse pointer enters the control area - say, change the background color slowly to a predefined color (let it be pink). I created a custom control template for that, and its essential part looks like this:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <!-- Control layout stuff with ContentPresenter -->
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        To="Pink" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, I can't make this animation work. I always get an unhandled exception of type:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll with additional information like this:
>   'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path
>   'Background.(0)'

I googled this problem. It seems, I need to use the correct syntax for the TargetProperty to animate. However, I tried a lot of variants like the following ones and they all do not work in my case:

- `Background.Color`
- `(Panel.Background).Color`
- `(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`
- `(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`

Am I searching not in the right direction?

Comment: Just use `TargetProperty=Background` should work. In case it doesn't recognize `Pink` as a Brush, you might need to use a `StaticResource` for that but afaik it should work with the name alone as long it is a pre-defined color name.

Comment: @Adwaenyth, sure it does not work. Additional information: 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.

Comment: Mh... try as `Storyboard.TargetProperty=(GroupBox.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`, does that work then as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158500/wpf-animate-background-color)?

Comment: @Adwaenyth, still the same unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll. Additional information: 'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TargetElement` needs an initial Setter in its Style in order to get the Animation to work.

**Example**

```
<GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                                <Grid Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <Grid.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Grid.Style>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Pink" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GroupBox.Style>
        <Button Content="test" Width="200" Height="50"></Button>
    </GroupBox>
```

After doing this, you can easily use `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"`

Comment: Yes, really, and I even thought about this: how can ColorAnimation know how to animate from a non-set color to pink? However, I need to do this the universal way, i.e. without setting a predefined color for the main layout grid. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: BTW, even the simple property setting in the Grid node helps: `<Grid Background="Blue">`.

Comment: You could define a default-background for the grid. The built-in default should be Transparent or White. Just set it again and you'll have a more generic approach.

Comment: Doesn't setting the Background to Transparent change the mouse behavior in the control? See also this [SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent). Is there a way to animate the background from Null to a specified color?

Comment: Not really. It doesnt matter **what** you initially set as Background as long you do set one. Wpf is not really pretty on some places but we have to deal with it