# How to animate or add transition to a label's foreground color change?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is for a WPF application. I have a label with some text. What I want is that when the mouse is hovered over the label, the color of the text will slowly change to another color. When the mouse is moved away, the color will slowly change back to its original color.

My code in MainWindow.xaml:

```
     <Label
            x:Name="mLabel"
            Height="32.446"
            Margin="18.339,65.5,0,0"
            Padding="5,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Hello"
            FontSize="36"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="#19418D"
            MouseEnter="MLabel_MouseEnter"
            MouseLeave="MLabel_MouseLeave"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="MLabel_MouseLeftButtonUp"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomFont}"
            UseLayoutRounding="False">
            <Label.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform Angle="360.086" />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Label.RenderTransform>
        </Label>
```

My code in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void MLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mLabel.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#7BA8FE"));
}

private void MLabel_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mLabel.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#19418D"));
}
```

Right now, it's an instant change from dark blue to light blue. But I want that change to happen slowly in a few seconds.

This question is different because I am working with foreground color of a label control here but the other solution is for background color of buttons which has a different way to implement.

Comment: You should not modify XAML in code xaml can do so on its own without any codebehind

Comment: Have you tried anything? Start with tutorials regarding animations in WPF. It won't take long, but then you would be able to solve similar easy tasks without asking someone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wpf animate background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158500/wpf-animate-background-color)

Comment: This is for a rectangle but will have the desired effect with some modifications https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/927/wpf-color-animation-in-solidcolorbrush.aspx

Comment: @Sinatr yes, I found that page while searching but couldn't make it work. for example, I tried to implement <Label.Triggers> since mine is a label and not a button but it didn't work.

Comment: @RandomCoder I tried <Label.Triggers> instead of <Rectangle.Triggers> but it didn't work. Maybe label has a different way to implement.

Comment: @ImTryIng Here is a label specific example. Start a new project and test it out. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6badd4d4-d66a-435e-8f27-98a70f2e693b/how-to-change-colour-of-label-on-rollover-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this example [Label Hover](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6badd4d4-d66a-435e-8f27-98a70f2e693b/how-to-change-colour-of-label-on-rollover-in-wpf?forum=wpf)

Create a new project and just after your window Title

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
```

paste the following

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyLabel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <ColorAnimation To="#7BA8FE" Duration="0:0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <ColorAnimation To="#19418D" Duration="0:0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

The drop any label on the screen from the toolbox and change it's style property to the following

```
<Label Content="Label" Style="{DynamicResource MyLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
```

[image][image]