# WPF how to properly animate color changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-animation

While it is it easy to one-off background change and it already has many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14158951/3096657), how can I consistently animate color *changing* (e.g. not once, not to single color). 
To give a toy example of the problem, lets say I have a `Rectangle` and three `RadioButton`s named "Red", "Blue" and "Green", how can I animate Rectangle's Fill color so that it is corresponding to checked radio button (e.g. whenever you click "Blue" and rectangle turns Blue)?

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource ColorChangingStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton Name="Red" Content="Red" GroupName="Group1" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton Name="Green" Content="Green" GroupName="Group1"/>
    <RadioButton Name="Blue" Content="Blue" GroupName="Group1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem I am facing right now is, whenever there is more than one animation attached to the `Rectangle`'s Fill color, it fails miserably in various ways due to animation precedence, for example if there are multiple triggers for "Red", "Green" and "Blue":

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Blue}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="ToBlue">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Blue" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

and you click "Green" while Fill is Blue, it will stay Blue (because "ToBlue" was defined below "ToGreen"). Worse yet if you attempt to remove "ToBlue" beforehand:

```
<RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ToBlue"/>
```

it will animate from the default color to Green rather than from Blue to Green.

Comment: Bonus points: it would work continuously even if target color is changed while animation is in progress.

Comment: @Frenchy your suggested solution with 'push' semantics from RadioButtons looks valid to me (not me voting). Though undoubtebly `VisualStateManager` is more elegant one because it allows easier bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the problem is .... it IS a "BUG". Triggers are old method of "styling" elements. The new method is using [VisualStates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=netframework-4.8)

an example would be:

NOTE: this example will not work for you.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="ColorStates">

      <VisualState Name="ToGreen">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation To="Green" 
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>

      <VisualState Name="ToBlue">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation To="Blue" 
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>

      <VisualState Name="ToRed">
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

and then for changing the state you can use a bit c#

```
 VisualStateManager.GoToState(YOUR_CONTROL, "YOUR_STATE", true);
```

Or if it's too ugly, you can make a **State Behavior**

```
public class StateBehavior 
{
      public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("State", 
                                              typeof(string), 
                                              typeof(StateBehavior),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(null, StateChanged));

      internal static void StateChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) 
      {
          if (args.NewValue != null)
             VisualStateManager.GoToState((FrameworkElement)target, args.NewValue, true);
      }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<YOUR_CONTROL local:StateBehavior.State="{Binding Path=YOUR_STATE_DATA, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**BONUS**

you can use [Transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstategroup.transitions?view=netframework-4.8) for some effects  (Ik its off-topic)

PS: Sorry for not showing how to solve your problem. (I'm just too lazy for switching to Windows, I'm on Linux currently)

Comment: Nice, works flawlessly but most importantly consistently. In addition, even the 'basic' example fulfills the bonus point - animation is perfectly fluid. Just a note to implementors: you will most likely need need to define new instance `<SolidColorBrush/>` for the Rectangle otherwise the app crashes on some cryptic exception.