# How can I access the Color from the SolidColorBrush of the Background in a ColorAnimation in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to do my own button style. I want to the `MouseEnter` and the `MouseLeave` event to use the color chosen for `BorderBrush` and `Background` respectively.

My style code is:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Margin="-1"
                                        CornerRadius="3"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderThickness="0.7"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                            Margin="-1"
                                            x:Name="MyContentPresenter"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="{Binding (CHOSEN BORDER BRUSH)}" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="{Binding (CHOSEN BACKGROUND BURSH)}" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

My usage is:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}"
                Height="30"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="10"
                Background="Green"
                BorderBrush="ForestGreen">
```

I would like to do that using only XAML, without any converters, if possible.

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14158951/3137337

Comment: @emoacht I don't see it. I need the binding on the color. on this question the color is given

Comment: You can't bind to a dynamic value in an animation object as it needs to be frozen. You would have to define the colors as resources.

Comment: Alternatively, extend the Button class and then create a new animation with the current colors in C#. You would then have to create a new animation whenever the Background or BorderBrush changes (in case you want this to be dynamic).

Comment: @BionicCode I have the color as resources, aswell the brushes. What I wanted to achieve is that the programmer sets a bursh for the ```Background``` and a brush for the ```BorderBursh```. Then, when mouse enters, I would like to paint the background with the color from the borderbrush

Comment: Either use a simple Trigger (no animation) to accomplish this, or let the programmer override a resource key (to define a new color). Usually you aim for a homogeneous look throughout the application, hence elements like buttons are customized by (global) styles that reference predefined resources like colors or images. Therefore, the second solution to enforce the use of resources like a `Color` with a key `ButtonBackgroundColor` shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are some limitations to using storyboards in a style, see [Animate in a Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#animate-in-a-controltemplate).

However, the easy solution would be to use the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` from the default `Button` template. Below, the `"IsDefaulted"` property is unchanged from the default `Button` template, `Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"` is modified, and `Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false"` is added:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
   <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
 </Trigger>
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
   <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
 </Trigger>
 ...
```

Or, try naming the brushes, see also [How to: Animate a Property by Using a Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-property-by-using-a-storyboard) and use a behavior, see [XAML Behaviors for WPF](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki). Use of `behaviors` is not shown here.

```
<Button.Background>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Name="backgroundBrush" Color="Green" />
</Button.Background>

...

<Button.BorderBrush>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Name="borderBrush" Color="ForestGreen" />
</Button.BorderBrush>

...

<Storyboard>
  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                  To="{Binding ElementName=borderBrush, Path=Color}" 
                  Duration="0:0:0.1" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: please, where in the ```Style``` I add this code? I need to ```TemplateBinding``` my ```Border``` in my ```ControlTemplate``` to the ```Background``` of the ```Button```. Then, the animation will switch between them. I couldnt follow what you meant here

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: I need this to be on a style in ```App.xaml```. I couldnt make it to work. Maybe is because I'm overriding  the default control template with my own, as is in my original question. I just gave up and created 4 kinds of ```button``` with pre determined colors and effects